# How does BIOS or any other firmware communicate with a storage device in order to achieve the first-stage boot loader goals?

Tags: bootloader, storage

When booting, the firmware in BIOS-CMOS needs to recognize which volume has a boot loader to things effectively starting to become highly operationals. But, at this stage, I think, there is no driver, nor a handler of a specific filesystem, available to help BIOS/UEFI to find the boot loader file and load it into RAM. So, how such operation is done? Is there a protocol that manufactures of involved devices follow in order to provide crude communication between CPU and storage device?

Comment: Can you please make a more clear sentence, because this is hard to understand: " to things effectively starting to become highly operationals."? If you have to make it a little longer for the sake of clarity, that's OK.

Comment: Not a full answer as I don't think this is electronics design but computer specific and possibly should be on another site.  Basically the BIOS searches bootable drives for a boot sector.  If found copies it into RAM and runs it.

Comment: I think that is more computer technology than electrical engineering question. Many assumptions are also wrong. You can read wikipedia page about how UEFI works and for more info refer to official UEFI standard specifications.

Comment: This question is better suited for the SuperUser SE site. Voting to migrate it there where it will likely get better answers.

Comment: @EdinFifić, I was somewhat "poetic" at this point. I meant that without a proper boot loader, the operability of a computer/system would be small.

Comment: @WarrenHill, Justme and Adam Lawrence, I was looking for a site in StackExchange to post this correctly. The first I found that had boot as a tag was this (I've disregarded Stack Over Flow. I've looked in Computer Science, Software Engineering etc.). I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily correct that the BIOS cannot contain filesystem code, although older BIOSes were fairly crude in this regard, and read a [single sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) into RAM. This sector, known as the MBR, contains code to read a few more sectors from a partition on the disk. It's important to stress that loading the MBR itself is quite simple: It's the first sector on the disk, and it's checked by verifying two bytes to see if they're equal to a hardcoded sequence.

Reading the disk itself is easy, because the BIOS needs to provide a disk read routine [anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH=02h:_Read_Sectors_From_Drive).

Nowadays, UEFI machines have large enough firmware storage that they can easily incorporate filesystem drivers, GUIs for BIOS setup, and the like. As an example, a FAT16 driver can be achieved in [less than 8 KB of AVR code](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=155446.0); a FAT32 driver on x86 can certainly be achieved within an order of magnitude. Meanwhile, my laptop's BIOS update image is 16 MiB, which is plenty of space if the code is well-written and compact.

Comment: Ok! About the filesystem. I've got. But about driver, the way that the CPU uses the storage device?

Comment: @DanielBandeira Also small and easy to fit and the BIOS must provide it *anyway* for operating systems to perform disk reads. [This is what a simple call to read a disk looks like](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/blob/master/14-checkpoint/boot/disk.asm); the `int 13h` routine is provided by the BIOS.

Comment: What a beautiful tutorial @nanofarad.  Could not be more simple. :)